# Meaning of socket.io listen a express server?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am reading socket.io's how to, this follow code I can not understand :

**Server (app.js)**

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);
```

what is the meaning of `io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`, Is it just use same configurations with socket.io and express?

Comment: OP, if you feel your question isn't well answered, add a comment to explain what's missing.

Answer (score 2):

The listen function takes as argument an http event handler such as the ones you get from `http.Server` (it can also accept a port, in which case the `listen` functions [creates the http server](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/94905500e492d8128e17a355ebf9885bbc4bf93b/lib/index.js#L207)).

The [`http.createServer`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) function creates an http Server from a request listener. And that's what's an express application : a request listener, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L27) :

```
function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };
  ...
  return app;
}
```

Of course you don't need express to use socket.io, you may simply pass to `listen` a port or any instance of `http.Server`.